# What is the meaning of "he made me"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

On phone, Tobin is talking to Doug, who is on bus & tailing another guy.

> Tobin: Keep talking to me. What's going on? ls he carrying the
>   satchel?
>
> Doug: OK, he's got the satchel. But l think **he made me**.

Comment: In the context in which I think this dialogue takes place, **he made me** means _"he found out who I really am."_

Comment: @P.E.Dant: The answer is strong with this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of [the many definitions of "make"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/make), this is the relevant one:

13. *(transitive, US slang)* To recognise, identify.

The guy that Doug is tailing has seen him and has recognised him, either recognising Doug personally or recognising what Doug is doing (tailing the guy).